# How to Return Multiple Values from CASE clause in Where Condition

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a codition in which i need to use multiple parameters in `where` clause 
using Conditional operator.
I have written the following query and in this condition i can't use `in` clasue.
Kindly guide me how can i return multiple parameters from case clause.

```
select * from cardimport
where
STATUS = CASE
WHEN STATUS = ''
THEN 'F'
ELSE STATUS
END
```

When Status in `null` i want to return `'F'` and `'V'`. Right now its returning Only `'F'`

**EDITED**

```
select *
from CARDIMPORT
where STATUS =   CASE
WHEN $P{status} = ''
THEN 'E'
ELSE $P{status}
END
```

When the STATUS is null, I want to show the records of from all status, that are `'E'`, `'I'`, `'A'`

Comment: Here condition should be wrong status =status display all records without null. Why are need two values

Comment: @Kirman88 - Show us the input and desired output.

Comment: can you show example table data & show what result you want. You should be using "IS NULL" to check for null, not =''. Is STATUS a column in the table?

Comment: @LalitKumarB status=status display all rows. see condition

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @Kirmani88 where are parameters? your query involves no parameter at all.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude Ah! I didn't see that on both sides OP has column name, I thought it to be parameter on left side of operator.

Comment: Example data & expected results would help here - also what database, as this could affect the answer.

Comment: @Kirmani88 Why have you accepted a wrong answer? You said you are using Oracle, and the accepted answer is no way related to Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try following,

```
Declare @status nvarchar(50) = 'XXXX'
select 
    * 
from cardimport
where
1 = case when isnull(@status,'') = '' then 1 
    else
        case when status = @status then 1 else 0 end
    end
```

It will give you all the rows when status is null and when status is not null then give you only matching data.

Comment: Thanks :) \This query works fine when no data is provided, but when i enter some data it returns empty result set

Comment: You want all the data in which status is not null and null status with 'F' and 'V' ?

Comment: See I have updated the answer, actually I am not getting your desire result when status is not null !!!

Comment: yes, When `Status` is null ,then I want to show data of all `Status` and When user Specify some status, then i want to show data of only that particular Status.

Comment: The edited query is returning the same result set for both `Null` and `Not Null`

Comment: I am using oracle, in IReport Scenario  can't declare variable here

Comment: How could you pass status to your query the you need to create procedure for that..

Comment: It's just logic you can implement this to your scenario and accordingly modify query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82495/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-kirmani88).

Comment: How is this answer related to Oracle at all?

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't need CASE, rather you need **NVL** and **NVL2**.

If I understand your requirement correctly, you need a particular row when the status value is NULL, else when not null then return all the rows.

For example, in the below example from `EMP` table. If the parameter value is `NULL`, I expect only that row where `comm` = `300` else when `not null` then return all rows.

**NULL**

```
SQL> VAR a NUMBER;
SQL> EXEC :a := NULL

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT empno, comm FROM emp WHERE NVL(comm, 9999) = NVL2(:a, NVL(comm, 9999), 300);

     EMPNO       COMM
---------- ----------
      7499        300
```

**NOT NULL**

```
SQL> EXEC :a :=1400

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT empno, comm FROM emp WHERE NVL(comm, 9999) = NVL2(:a, NVL(comm, 9999), 300);

     EMPNO       COMM
---------- ----------
      7369
      7499        300
      7521        500
      7566
      7654       1400
      7698
      7782
      7788
      7839
      7844
      7876
      7900
      7902
      7934

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The above uses the following logic:

- If, the value passed is NULL, then return row where `COMM = 300`.
- Else if, value passed is NOT NULL, then return all the rows.

Comment: OP is not clear if he is using Oracle or MySQL - the latter doesn't have NVL/NVL2 functions.

Comment: @PaulF OP has tagged `Oracle`.

Comment: At the time of my comment OP still had MySQL as a tag - that was nearly 6 yrs ago now.

Comment: @PaulF I agree, also the accepted answer is no way related to Oracle. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

Is possible to return collection from case. 
KU$_VCNT is predefined collection (`KU$_VCNT is table of varchar2(4000)` ).

```
with c_table as (select null status from dual
 union all 
select  'A' status from dual
union all 
select  'B' status from dual
)
select status,case when status is null then KU$_VCNT('NULL1','NULL2') else KU$_VCNT('A','B','C','D') end  from c_table
where status member of 
case when status is null then KU$_VCNT('NULL1','NULL1') else KU$_VCNT('A','B','C','D')  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from cardimport t
where
t.STATUS in 
case  when t.STATUS is null then 
(select 'F' from dual union select 'V' from dual ) else t.STATUS end
```

This kind of the condition is require. But i find that there may be something wrong in your understanding because you tried to match the null status with 'F'/'V' which will never turn into true condition

Above is just the condition if you want to have in clause with case when that return multiple records

Comment: `WHERE 1 =1` is always `TRUE`. It will return all the rows. And rows where `status` is **NULL** will be ignored as you cannot compare **NULL** with any value.

Comment: IN statement near t.Status is not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about doing it in the `ORACLE` but the same can be achieved in `Microsoft SQL SERVER` by the following method:

```
DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(1)=''

SELECT * from cardimport
where
STATUS IN(SELECT Status FROM cardimport WHERE (@Status='' AND status IN('E','I','A')) OR (@Status<>'' AND status=status))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @active VARCHAR(10) = 0
SELECT * FROM department 
WHERE  `enter code here`
(
    (1 = CASE WHEN @active = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END and (active is null or active = 0))
 or (1 = CASE WHEN @active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END and active = 1)
)
```